# Sendmail works fine but PHP is unable to use that

Tags: email, redhat, email-server, sendmail, lamp

I have a problem sending mail with PHP on a LAMP (redhat 7 server). I have configured `sendmail`, with which I am able to send email using the following:

```
$ sendmail toemail@something.com <press enter>
message body <press enter>
ctrl+d (sends message)
```

and the message is received by any mentioned email address, successfully.

But when I use the PHP scripts (working fine on other servers), PHP scripts are unable to send any email.

No error is there in `/etc/mail/maillog/` and I have tried with different paths in `php.ini` in `sendmail_path`
e.g:

`/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`

`/usr/sbin/sendmail -t`

`/usr/sbin/sendmail`

None of the three does anything.

permission for `/usr/sbin/sendmail` is `666`.

Any of the possible PHP scripts that works everywhere, does not work in this new  environment. One of the scripts which I tried is as below:

```
<?php if(mail("receipient@domain.com","A Subject Here","Hi there,\nThis email was sent using PHP's mail function.")) print "Email successfully sent"; else print "An error occured"; ?>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can edit your post and add your actual PHP script(s).

Comment: permission for /usr/sbin/sendmail is 666 - has to be 755. Also check audit logs.

Comment: Try to test PHP in interactive mode - send letter just from console:
1). php -a  
2). mail('your-mail-address-here', 'test subject', 'test message');

Comment: Thanks Everybody. It's working now.
The permissions were set to 755 and it worked after disabling the SELINUX firewall.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the path you are using for `sendmail_path` in php.ini is wrong. There is a missing `/` in the line, a typing mistake or a copy/paste failure I guess:

It should be like:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -I

/usr/sbin/sendmail -t

/usr/sbin/sendmail
```

You can find out the correct path for yourself, if you have access to the shell, type the following:

```
whereis sendmail
```

And you should also set permission to sendmail's binary to `755` using `chmod` so that php script is able to execute it.

For further diagnostic you should also check your apache error log (`/var/log/httpd/error_log` or similar location). You can find out your exact error log location for your default/virtual host by looking at the value for the following parameter in `apache.conf` or virtual host's `.conf` file:

```
ErrorLog
```